# How to make Drupal's multisite algorithm ignore the domain name part

Tags: drupal, apache2, dns

I currently develop Drupal web sites using its multi-site feature that allows me to have a single code base and support multiple distinct settings per each site.

I set up a dev server and I was quite happy with my arrangement of domains like example.com.local (not that happy because I had to perform a small conversion before entering production, but still quite happy) and the thing used to work well. Too bad I recently started to work at places outside the LAN in which my dev server resides--mostly at clients' places where I need to demo their sites. First of all I set up a dyndns.org account and the server is accessible through the Internet.

Unfortunately the whole domain-based multi-site ungracefully fell down, since I'm now accessing the server via myservername.dyndns.org and Drupal's algorithm takes the domain name into account, so I'm forced to use at least the TLD as part of the directory name (namely sites/local.example.com). So I decided to switch to directory-based multi-site, and now I'm able to access my server from inside the LAN using myservername.local/example.com (having renamed the sites/ subdirectories accordingly). You should easily see why this is suboptimal, since when I browse to myservername.dyndns.org/example.com Drupal looks for sites/org.example.com. I temporarily ended up making a link from sites/org.example.com to sites/local.example.com but again, this does not scale well If and when I'll have to drop dyndns.org for, say, dev.mycorporatesite.com...

Is there any other possibility? I have full access to the server, I can change Apache2's configs, .htaccess and all the stuff.

Comment: Please divide your question into logical paragraphs - it is difficult to read it now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against referencing drupal multisites in folders but instead would set up your server to have a fixed domain name and each site in a subdomain.

So your dev server is at mydevserver.com

and then each site could be

client1.mydevserver.com
client2.mydevserver.com

etc.

If you also at the same time as creating these, you move the files folder from the default to whatever the live site will be i.e.

sites/livesite.com/files

Then when you have to go live, all the references will be correct (if you are drupal 7 this might not be an issue)